# Drop rows while iterating through groups in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

for a dataset like:

```
te = {'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'B':[0,3,6,0,5,7]}
df = DataFrame(te, index = range(6))
vol = 0
```

I'd like to groupby `A` and iter through the groups after the groupby function:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('A'):
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if row['B'] <= 0:
            group = group.drop(i)
            vol += row['A']
```

Somehow my code didn't work and the dataframe `df` remains the same as before the `for` loop. I need to use the `groupby()` method because the rows of dataset will increase through another loop outside this one, is there any methods to drop rows in groups from `groupby`? Or how to filter it out while also summing the `row['A']`?

Comment: What is desired output from input?

Comment: @jezrael I'd like to have a dataframe just like the input `df` but without the rows fit the condition `if row['B'] <= 0` and the sum value `vol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do both operations separately without loop:

```
vol = df.A[df.B <= 0].sum()
df = df[df.B > 0]  # equivalent to drop
```